# get method return No_Value on optional

Tags: android, java-8, option-type

In the below example, initially, this.mMyBoundServiceHandlerThread is null. i want to initialize that object as shown in the 
code posted below.

when the code is executed, i receive the following:

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException: No value present
```

would you please let me know why .get() return empty value?

**code**:

```
Optional<MyBoundServiceHandlerThread> s = Optionals.toOptional(this.mMyBoundServiceHandlerThread);
    s
            .map(x -> new MyBoundServiceHandlerThread(HANDLER_THREAD_MyBoundServiceForJob02, MyBoundServiceForJob02.this))
            .orElse(new MyBoundServiceHandlerThread(HANDLER_THREAD_MyBoundServiceForJob02, MyBoundServiceForJob02.this));
    s.get().start();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be:

```
s.map(x -> new MyBoundServiceHandlerThread(HANDLER_THREAD_MyBoundServiceForJob02, MyBoundServiceForJob02.this))
 .orElse(new MyBoundServiceHandlerThread(HANDLER_THREAD_MyBoundServiceForJob02, MyBoundServiceForJob02.this))
 .start();
```

`s` may be an empty `Optional`, so calling `s.get()` may throw an exception.

The point of calling `orElse` is to supply a default value if the `Optional` is empty, but you are doing nothing with that value.

P.S. I'm not sure your `map` and `orElse` call make sense, since your `map` ignores the value of the `Optional`. You could replace that entire code snippet with this equivalent statement:

```
new MyBoundServiceHandlerThread(HANDLER_THREAD_MyBoundServiceForJob02, MyBoundServiceForJob02.this).start();
```

I don't think that's what you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

> would you please let me know why .get() return empty value?

In this case it would only return an empty Optional if and only if `this.mMyBoundServiceHandlerThread` is `null` therefore the Optional returned has an absent state and when invoking `.get()` upon an empty Optional it will yield a "No value present" as the Optional has an absent state (no value present).

if you're sure that the Optional returned should not be empty then you'll need to debug and track the `mMyBoundServiceHandlerThread` identifier in your program.

On another note, Optional's should not be used to replace "if" statements, I am saying this because currently, you're ignoring the element from `map` identified as `x` therefore you may be better off refactoring to:

```
MyBoundServiceHandlerThread result = null;
if(this.mMyBoundServiceHandlerThread != null) 
    result = new MyBoundServiceHandlerThread(HANDLER_THREAD_MyBoundServiceForJob02, MyBoundServiceForJob02.this)
```

Also, note that your alternative value supplied in the `orElse` is the same as the one passed to the `map` method which seems unusual. you may want to look into that if you're going to proceed with the use of an Optional.